# Error while creating a join in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT permission.bit,permission.name  
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN permission ON user.role & permission.bit
WHERE user.id = 1
```

I have query like this and I get this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'bit'.

Comment: `ON user.col = permiss.col` and use `AND` instead of `&` to join conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think you'r trying to do a bitwise comparison

```
SELECT  permission.bit,permission.name  
FROM user LEFT JOIN permission 
   ON user.role & permission.bit <> 0
WHERE user.id = 1
```

Comment: ya thats true, I tried the query which you have posted but still have the same error message, thanks

Comment: I think user.role is not a bit type field, is it? I believe "role" has a number of possible values rather than being TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Actually, if this is a bitwise comparison, both .role and .bit should be integers. So for example if role = 10, then join would give true for bit values 2 and 8